# CSV to formatted document table

Tags: csv, google-sheets, google-docs

How to populate a formatted document table with data from CSV?

I have a CSV (data) in Google Sheets and I want to convert it to a formatted Google Docs (style).
Google Docs is preferable for it's integrability with the Google Sheets (CSV), but solutions with `.docx`, `.pdf` are ok.

Example: [input --> output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QIO1o.jpg)

### More background and research

This's similar to Microsoft Access reports. I know I can paste the CSV table from Google Sheets to Google Docs, but the style is always messed up. If I use paste values only using `Ctrl-Shift-V`, then it pastes values separated by tabs not a table.

A possible workaround is to convert `CSV` to `gsheets`, format the spreadsheet, and paste it with its styles in google docs, but it's impractical for multiple CSV files.

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Can I ask you about your question? 1. About `I have a CSV (data) in Google Sheets`, in this case, the CSV data is put in a cell? 2. About `I want to convert it to a formatted Google Docs (style).`, can you provide the sample `a formatted Google Docs (style)`? 3. And also, can you provide the sample input and output you expect as the images? By the way, I thought that in your situation, Google Apps Script might be useful. How about this?

Comment: @Tanaike 1. Yes. 2. Example: just any Google Docs table with specified font, color, cell background, and borders. 3. Sample input: CSV of term/definition, sample output: Google Docs table of term/definition but with styles applied. Give me time to address more concrete example by images...

Comment: I provided input/output example in the question.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I could confirm the sample input and output situation. When I saw both images, the input situation has no header row. But, the output situation has the header row. And, the font family is different between the input and the output situation. In this case, I think that it is required to know the detail specification of your goal. And, I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Can I ask you about the method for achieving your goal? Because, in this case, I think that it is required to use the script. But from your replying, I cannot understand about it.

Comment: @Tanaike Yes. The idea is basically to separate between data and design. The method can be similar to Pandoc or R Markdown Knittr. It is a script to apply style on a csv of data.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, from your replying, I cannot still understand about your question. But I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of the solution. I deeply apologize I cannot resolve your issue soon.

Comment: @Tanaike Thanks. I think after reading a bit about Google Apps API and the possible integration between Google Sheets and Google Docs, it seems that the closest method to achieve this is through Google Script.